# Setting Content-Type header (multipart/data) dynamically using Httpinterceptor

Tags: angular, typescript

---

---

I want to upload CSV and I'm using HttpInterceptor as a middleware.

For normal request, it is working fine but while uploading CSV I want to change my request header as 'multipart/data'.

Please follow the code -

```
export class NoopInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let token = this._tokenManagerService.getToken();
        const newRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `${token}`
            }

        });
              return next.handle(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Please give me some suggestion for same.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code; post code.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the screenshot and added my code now.

Answer (score 0):

your Http Interceptor function should be like.

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
                req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')});
            }

            req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set( 'Authorization': ${token}``)});
            return next.handle(req);
        }
```

now you need to set `multipart/data` header in your service function. so itercepter check if found then not set.

Comment: After using this approch it is adding mutipart/data as a content type in request header like 'content-type:multipart/data', but it is not adding boundary along with multipart/data.